# Excel: replace part of cell's string value

Tags: excel

I have a large spreadsheet with a column called "Roles". In this columns are values like:

```
ROLES
Author
Author;
Publishing; Author;
Something Else; Author; Publishing
```

There are other columns where the word "Author" may exist.

What I need to do is look for "Author" in my "Roles" column only, and replace it with "Authoring", without losing anything before or after it. i.e. the end result should be:

```
ROLES
Authoring
Authoring;
Publishing; Authoring;
Something Else; Authoring; Publishing
```

I tried the `FIND`- and `REPLACE`-functions, but that replaced the entire cell value, not just a portion of it.

```
=IF(FIND("Author",[@Roles],1),REPLACE("Author",1,6,"Authoring"))
```

Can anyone help? I'd rather not us a VB solution, as I'm not familiar with how to do that, so hopefully there is a formula based way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you need to do is as follows:

1. List item
2. Select the entire column by clicking once on the corresponding letter or by simply selecting the cells with your mouse.
3. Press Ctrl+H.
4. You are now in the "Find and Replace" dialog. Write "Author" in the "Find what" text box.
5. Write "Authoring" in the "Replace with" text box.
6. Click the "Replace All" button.

That's it!

Comment: Oh good grief! You're exactly right.. this is the best and quickest way to do this. I clearly did something wrong last time I tried that, as it was replacing values in other columns too, but your concise steps did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: This is not answer to the question asked! Look for SUBSTITUTE function from the answer from darkajax below. And should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: this is not working for me. whole cell content is replaced in my case

Comment: This is working for me in Office 2010 Excel version 14.0.7214.5000.

Answer (score 73):

what you're looking for is SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Author","Authoring")
```

Will substitute Author for Authoring without messing with everything else

Comment: It turns out that using shaylh's answer is better for what I need, but your answer is great too, and did exactly what I wanted, based on teh question. (what I didn't says is that I have multiple replacements to do, and the Ctrl+H version works best for that). Cheers :)

Comment: Don't worry, if that's what you needed it's ok, at least  now you'll have options in case you need something different

Comment: I was searching for one function name in excel to do the same working as 'Replace' in oracle.. well I was searching for a while and at the end, here I got my proper answer.

Comment: If, like me, you occasionally use excel to generate SQL statements... what you're looking for is [ SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","''") ] to escape single quotes in the cell value, thus preventing garbage scripts!

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old but I had a similar need for this and I did not want to do the find and replace version. It turns out that you can nest the substitute method like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F149, "a", " AM"), "p", " PM")
```

In my case, I am using excel to view a DBF file and however it was populated has times like this:

```
9:16a
2:22p
```

So I just made a new column and put that formula in it to convert it to the excel time format.

Answer (score -2):

You have a character = `STQ8QGpaM4CU6149665!7084880820`, and you have a another column = `7084880820`.

If you want to get only this in excel using the formula: `STQ8QGpaM4CU6149665!`, use this:

```
=REPLACE(H11,SEARCH(J11,H11),LEN(J11),"")
```

H11 is an old character and for starting number use search option then for no of character needs to replace use len option then replace to new character. I am replacing this to blank.